# margin auto pushes div out of navbar

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a problem. 
The

```
 margin-left:auto 
 margin-right:auto
```

of my div pushes an other div out of the navbar.

i want both in the navbar how can i fix it ?

Here is my Code:

```css
body, html {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#navbar {
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background-color:#000000;
}

#div1 {
 width:300px;
 height:50px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 background-color:#FF0000;
 
}

#div2 {
 width:100px;
 height:50px;
 float:left;
 background-color:#00FF00;
 
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


</head>

<body>

<div id="navbar">

<div id="div1"></div>

<div id="div2"></div>


</div>



</body>
</html>
```

[codepen example](http://codepen.io/Lukas_Ertl/pen/xVLjMm#0)

I ignored this problem for so lang but now i realy have to know it.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: What is this supposed to look like? Perhaps changing the order? - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ZWJRzR

Comment: the black div is my navbar,the red one is my navigation and green one is a music player.

Comment: Obviously...but what is it the whole thing *supposed to look like?*

Comment: Having an auto margin on left and right centers the div. Where are you wanting to place these divs? Based off your code it seems like you want the green div positioned to the left of the red div within the black div, yes? But do you want the red div to be centered after that?

Comment: thas what i have so far http://imgur.com/PsR5SFq

Comment: i want the red one in the middle and the left one also in the black one but at the left

Answer (score 1):

you just have to put your div2 befor the div1

```css
body, html {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#navbar {
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background-color:#000000;
 
}

#div1 {
 width:300px;
 height:50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
  left: 50px;
 background-color:#FF0000;
 
}

#div2 {
 width:100px;
 height:50px;
 float:left;
 background-color:#00FF00;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="navbar">

 <div id="div2"></div>

 <div id="div1"></div>


</div>



</body>
```